# Tracking animals in videos with android

Tags: java, tensorflow2.0, tracking, yolo, coco

I am currently working on an android app to detect cows in videos and track them.

I use Java, YOLO, Coco dataset and tensorflow.

I have a question about tracking cows and identifying each one as they look all similar.

The goal is that the user will be able to select one cow to track.

can you suggest an idea to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the FPS of the video enables, you could determine where your cow is going by first saving it's location and "area coverage" on the image that the user selects. Then,  in subsequent frames, you can check nearby cows and determine which cow has the most "area" shared with the original. You repeat this precess to hopefully get a clean video of where your target cow is going. However, this approach requires the video to be pretty smooth, and the camera not to be jittery. It's a difficult task regardless. Imagine a human having to track a cow in a 10 FPS video. Good luck!